# delete Persistent group chat room multi user chat android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

i developed a group chat app using MultiUserChat(muc). problem is that i am unable to destroy a persistent chat room from openfire website. when i delete a group chat room it gets deleted from openfire but when i click on the delete group from android app then it appears again but without the name of group chat. For example consider a group "welcome (gf5wkw97wmd9ygzo) ". its name is "welcome" and room id is "gf5wkw97wmd9ygzo". but when i delete it and click on the deleted group from android app then it appears only with room id, i.e with "gf5wkw97wmd9ygzo" only. i here are screenshots. after creating or before deleting a group chat room named as "welcom" it looks like: 
**welcome (nv8vb53l5q88kf9r)**

after deleting welcome group from openfire website it show following message and group doesn't appear.
**Room destroyed successfully**
from here not problems is there

but when i selects this group from android app and refresh the openfire web page then it looks like:
**nv8vb53l5q88kf9r**

please note that here only room id: "nv8vb53l5q88kf9r" appears without group name which was "welcome" and it is not persistent any more.

exact is the case when i delete the group chat room from android app using following code:

```
muc = new MultiUserChat(xmppConnection, roomId);
muc.join(jid); 
muc.destroy("was tesing room", null);
```

please help me in this regard

Comment: my reputation is 8 points so i can't add screenshots.

Comment: Add a link to the screenshot and I'll edit the image itself in

Comment: please find the links    1) after creating group name "welcome":  [http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=33mpgk0&s=8#.VHcQw3gZXVM]      2) after deleting the group either from android app or from openfire website:  [http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=9ko86t&s=8#.VHcRnHgZXVM]  and finally when i click on group from android app and refresh the openfire page then only room id is displayed. the link is: [http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=287ka69&s=8#.VHcSQngZXVM]

Comment: please note that room id given in the question is different as compared to links of screenshots

Answer (score 1):

```
new MultiUserChat(xmppConnection, roomId);
```

This line creates the room immediately in openfire; Once you send the Destroy request it will delete the room.

But when you select the room in android check your code if you are using the above line with out checking room exist or not,in that case check before the above line use getRoomInfo(); this will return Item not found then just clean that room from bookmarks... else join and listen the messages.

the actual room 'welcome(nv8vb53l5q88kf9r)' is deleted and new room is created with jid 'nv8vb53l5q88kf9r' and you have not sent the configuration form yet so it does not have name ; so it is showing as nv8vb53l5q88kf9r.

And Also check is openfire is sending any IQ on delete to the room participants; then listen and take action according to that.

Hope this helps.